Powering Raspberry Pi 5B with li-ion battries: Pi 5 just won't boot, stops booting mid-way
I've been pulling my hair for a couple of weeks now. Changed batteries, changed BMS, changed step-down module. No avail.
I am trying to run RPi 5B with 4 li-ion cells in 2S2P config. 2S2P -> BMS -> Step-Down Module The voltage is 4.98V to 5.01V (not 5.1V, could that be an issue?). I tried 3A and 5A BMS and step-down modules. Didn't work.
I even used a female USB A connected to the battery pack and tried connecting a USB cable to the Type C pin — still nothing.
OS's tried: RPi OS Lite and Android 14 Lineage OS (unofficial); No peripherals attached.
Behavior: Doesn't automatically start booting. When the button is pressed, the green LED starts blinking and then turns red mid-way of booting.
Is there a way to disable the power quality check at the boot?
(since I know how much food my toddler needs, not trying to be "that" parent here)
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Could you explain what BMS is?

@dingo27mobile OMG Thanks! Turns out the only difference between dead and living was using the 2x 5V and 2x GND pins! Also, I need to get rid of cheap jumper wires maybe that'll help further.

@Seamus BMS: Battery Management System. Protects battery from undervoltage, overvoltage, shorts, etc.

The BMS is about charging batteries and mostly irrelevant. Your battery choice, the step-down converter, and HOW it is connected is the issue.
By default the Raspberry Pi 5 only will negotiate (USB-C PDU protocol) for the power and you likely don't have the ability to negotiate on your battery+stepdown side, so the Raspberry Pi 5 tests and quits as the 3A USB default is insufficient. Try the PSU_MAX_CURRENT setting in EEPROM, to avoid the negotiation and see if you can get further.
You may have a need for an Raspberry Pi 5 in your application, however, it is the most power-hungry and therefore the least desirable Raspberry Pi for battery-powered applications.

that should say see if you can get farther.

@jsotola if you are going to be pedantic further is normal when used as an adverb

@Milliways my comment is about can't  ... I'd edit it, but there are too many pending edits

"Try the PSU_MAX_CURRENT setting in eeprom...".  Your answer should explain what the setting should be.

(+1) Thanks! I didn't know about the eeprom settings. This will help further. My problem though was solved by connecting both 5v and both GND pins as suggested by @dingo27mobile

@Seamus Nah, the name is pretty self-explanatory, don't you think? Also, the documentation in the link was more than enough :)

@44yu5h: No, I didn't think it was self-explanatory... it should have been self-explanatory in the "official documentation", but failing that the post author could have made up for that. But happy to hear you got your issue resolved!

Try setting up 5.1 -5.15V to your converter (official RPI power supply is 5.1V too, because they know 5V is insufficient, yet still refuse to add proper power input for PI). use 5A step down, and if possible try to powering up through GPIO pins, two 5V and 2 ground pins. Use high quality copper cables, not chinese c**p, they can have high resistance. And definetly do not use chinese jumper wires whenever possible, they have really high resistance (ohms!)
